# Регулярное выражение, поиск русских слов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не работает граница **\b** для Юникода, поэтому пытаюсь найти вхождения русских слов вот так:

```
/(?:^|[^a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?:кот|бот)(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])/gm
```

Если искать по исходной строке "!кот?, <кот>, кот, байкот", то регулярное выражение возвращает правильные слова, но ненужными символами в начале: "!кот", "<кот", "кот"

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/QUoHof/1)

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать заглядывание назад `(?<![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])`, как вы используете заглядывание вперёд?

Comment: Какой язык? А то они все немножко по разному глючат